# Apply css to tr with custom data attribute in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table, each tr element has a custom data attribute and I want to apply style to certain values.

In HTML:

```
<table id="notify" class="t_notify">
<tr data-notify="101">
 <td>data</td>
 <td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr data-notify="102">
 <td>data</td>
 <td>data</td>
</tr>
<!-- and goes -->
</table>
```

With CSS:

```
.t_notify>tbody>tr{background:#BBB;}
.t_notify>tbody>tr:hover{background:transparent;}
```

I tried in Jquery to make this when I click in a certain tr element, for example:

```
$("#notify > tbody > tr").attr("[data-notify='101']").css({"background":"#CCC"});
```

But this doesn't work. I would like some help.

Comment: 1) `.attr` is an attribute getter/setter, not a DOM traversal method. 2) Is there a reason why you are not styling in the stylesheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Good Approach

Your query must be in the selector, like so :

```js
$("#notify > tbody > tr[data-notify='101']").css({"background":"#CCC"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="notify" class="t_notify">
<tr data-notify="101">
 <td>data</td>
 <td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr data-notify="102">
 <td>data</td>
 <td>data</td>
</tr>
<!-- and goes -->
</table>
```

### attr()

The `attr()` function returns the value of the attribute or sets it. In your case, you want neither. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `attr()` is intended to be used to get/set an attribute. It doesn't filter the elements in a collection. Instead you should use the attribute selector in the primary jQuery object.

Also, just to note that in the example below I changed the highlight colour as `#BBB` is very hard to spot against `#CCC`. I also amended the code to use `addClass()`, as you should avoid the use of `css()` where possible, as it ties the JS code too closely to the UI. Finally, I amended the CSS rules so that operator precedence works for all scenarios.

```js
$("#notify > tbody > tr[data-notify='101']").addClass('foo');
```

```css
.t_notify tr {
  background: #BBB;
}

.t_notify > tbody > tr:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
 
.t_notify tr.foo { 
   background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="notify" class="t_notify">
  <tr data-notify="101">
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-notify="102">
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- and goes on... -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the data in the selector: [Demon on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2f7L6gva/)

```js
$("#notify > tbody > tr[data-notify='101']").css({"background":"#CCC"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="notify" class="t_notify">
<tr data-notify="101">
 <td>data</td>
 <td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr data-notify="102">
 <td>data</td>
 <td>data</td>
</tr>
<!-- and goes -->
</table>
```

The CSS attribute selector matches elements based on the presence or value of a given attribute.

```
/* <a> elements with a title attribute */
a[title] {
  color: purple;
}

/* <a> elements with an href matching "https://example.org" */
a[href="https://example.org"] {
  color: green;
}

/* <a> elements with an href containing "example" */
a[href*="example"] {
  font-size: 2em;
}

/* <a> elements with an href ending ".org" */
a[href$=".org"] {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#notify > tbody > tr").attr("[data-notify='101']")`

should be:

`$("#notify > tbody > tr[data-notify='101']")`